# Bedeutung von "was in etwa so ist"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> 2013 trat er als SPD-Kandidat zur bayerischen Landtagswahl an, **was in etwa so ist**, als erhoffte sich Nigeria eine Medallie bei den Olympischen Winterspielen.

Wenn der fettgedruckte Teil nur "was so ist" oder "was etwa so ist" wäre, würde ich das gut verstehen. Aber was bedeutet hier "was in etwa so ist"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - ***'was etwa so ist'***

entspricht ganz genau

> - ***'was in etwa so ist'***

und ist synonym zu

> - ***'was ungefähr so ist'***

Answer (score 2):

Für mich klingt nur "was in etwa so ist" richtig. Das ist ja eine Wendung, um hier z. B. auszudrücken, dass der Eintritt eines Ereignisses "in etwa" so unwahrscheinlich ist wie der Eintritt eines vergleichbaren, offensichtlich unwahrscheinlichen Ereignisses, das aber nicht *genau* so beschaffen ist.

Hier ist es überzogen und ein Stilmittel. Für einen direkten Vergleich kann man sich das *was* sparen:

> Wenn man mit Endgeschwindigkeit flach auf Wasser aufschlägt, ist das so, als ob man auf Beton aufschlage.

(Das Ergebnis ist sehr ähnlich)

Comment: *Angeb'* Die Aussage ist aber falsch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E408JigEcFI